# Retrofit getting data from web throws null object reference

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to get data from web api but something is wrong and I can't figure it out.

My JSON looks like this

```
{
"partners": 
  [
   "partner1",
   "partner2",
   "partner3",
     ...     ,
   "partner150"
  ]
}
```

I have Table partners (ActiveAndroid) in which I would like to save all partners from api.

```
@Table(name = "Partners")
public class Partners extends Model {

    @Column(name = "Name")
    String name;

    public Partners() {}

    public Partners(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is my Pojo model class:

```
public class Partners extends ArrayList<String> {

@SerializedName("partners")
@Expose
public List<String> partners = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getPartners() {
    return partners;
}

public void setName(List<String> partners) {
    this.partners = partners;
}
```

}

This is my interface

```
public interface APIService {

        @GET("Partners")
        Call<Partners> getPartners();
}
```

This is my APIHelper class

```
public class APIHelper {

    public static final String PARTNERS_URL = "https://part-of-link.com/partners.json/";

    public static APIService apiService;

    public static APIService getApiService() {
        if (apiService == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(PARTNERS_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
            apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        }
        return apiService;
    }
}
```

And this is Fragment where I have an Button on which I would like to implement onClick method to get data from API and save it into Partners table.

```
public class DownloadMain extends Fragment implements Callback<Partners> {

    private Button dloadPartners;
    private Call<Partners> callPartners;
    public static APIService apiService;

    public DownloadMain() {}

    public DownloadMain newInstance() { return new DownloadMain(); }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_main, container, false);

        dloadPartners = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.downloadPartners);
        dloadPartners.setOnClickListener(btnListener);

        callPartners = APIHelper.getApiService().getPartners();
        callPartners.enqueue(this);

        return view;
    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnListener = (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            APIHelper helper = new APIHelper();
            apiService = helper.getApiService();

            Call<Partners> call = apiService.getPartners();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Partners>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Partners> call, Response<Partners> response) {
                       APIHelper helper = new APIHelper();
        helper.getApiService();

        Call<Partners> call = apiService.getPartners();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Partners>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Partners> call, Response<Partners> response) {

                List<String> partners = response.body().getPartners();
                Log.d(TAG, "Number of partners received: " + partners.size());
                    /*if (response.body() != null) {
                        ArrayList<String> partnersList;
                        partnersList = response.body();
                        Log.d("DOWNLOAD", String.valueOf(partnersList));
                    }*/
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Partners> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FAIL!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Partners> call, Response<Partners> response) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Partners> call, Throwable t) {

    }
}
```

And here is my problem. Everything works and there is no errors but when I click on button nothing happens.

So I presume I've made some mistake but I can't figure it out (First time doing with retrofit).

What I want on button click is to get all partners from web and save it into my Partners table.

**Question: Could somebody guide me and tell me what is wrong and help me to fix this?**

EDIT:

```
Button.OnClickListener btnListener = (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            APIHelper helper = new APIHelper();
            apiService = helper.getApiService();

            Call<ArrayList<String>> call = null;
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<String>>() {
                 @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Response<ArrayList<String>> response) {
                    ArrayList<String> partners = response.body();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Number of partners received: " + partners.size());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FAIL!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Error logs:

> Error:(68, 60) error:  is not abstract and does not
>   override abstract method
>   onResponse(Call>,Response>) in
>   Callback
>
> Error:(72, 53) error: cannot find symbol method body()
>
> Error:(69, 17) error: method does not override or implement a method
>   from a supertype
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: `callPartners.enqueue(this);`... The `onResponse` body is empty, so nothing should happen there, yes, however the button click look like it should do something. What have you tried to debug? Add some `Log` statements

Comment: which `Partners` class are you using for `Call<Partners>`? it should be the POJO one, not the ActiveAndroid, although using the AA one might cause an exception, which you don't have (as you say)

Comment: @cricket_007 I've made some changes in my onClick method and now I'm `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'retrofit2.Call com.example....rest.APIService.getPartners()' on a null object reference`

Comment: @Yazan I'm using POJO partners class

Comment: btw, why are you extending ArryList in your POJO?

Comment: @Yazan I've removed this(I was working with some tutorial so forgot to remove)

Comment: @Yazan could it be something wrong with my json? on link it looks like this `["partner1", "partner2", "partner3", "...", "partner150"]`

Comment: yes this means no field named `partners` so i think you have to remove the notation `@serializedName` or you don't even need POJO use `String[]` as `Call<String[]>` or `Call<String[].class>` not sure which one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is here in the onClick()

```
helper.getApiService();
```

you did not assign the service into the variable
change it to this:

```
apiService = helper.getApiService();
```

**EDIT:**
based on new updates i think you dont need to use a POJO
just use the following in your `Call`

`Call<ArrayList<String>>`

and to get response just use `response.body()` without `.partners()` .

try to replace it everywhere in your code and check

Comment: Now in onResponse method I get `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.example...pojo.Partners.getPartners()' on a null object reference` on this line `List<String> partners = response.body().getPartners();`
Could you please explain me what is causing this?

Comment: @Unknown19 `response` or `body()` is null, why ? i am not sure, could be a lot of reasons.

Comment: @Unknown19 did you use your POJO or the one I suggested?

Comment: Okay, then try it with the one I suggested. :)

Comment: @Seishin Tried, still the same error on the same line

Comment: @Yazan I was not able to change it because then it throws me few errors which I failed to fix.

Comment: @Unknown19 update your question add the errors that appeared when you changed to ...<String>

Comment: @Unknown19 it looks you've missed the `APIService` replace <Partners> with <ArrayList<String>> too

Comment: @Yazan you are right, I've changed it but still the same

Comment: @Yazan Now I get `Attempt to invoke interface method 'void retrofit2.Call.enqueue(retrofit2.Callback)' on a null object reference`on this line `call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<String>>() {`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your JSON response, your POJO class should be:

```
public class Partners {
  private ArrayList<String> partners = new ArrayList<>(0);

  // Get; Set methods //
}
```

Comment: Why? How to you intend to deserialize your response into a POJO? 
In your response you have just a field that is an array of Strings. 

Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I've tried but it throws me an error `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'retrofit2.Call com.example....rest.APIService.getPartners()' on a null object reference` on this line in fragment `Call<Partners> call = apiService.getPartners();`

Comment: Could you write down the POJO class you used? Also, could you write down the full exception?

Comment: This is POJO I used. 
`public class Partners  {

    @SerializedName("partners")
    @Expose
    public ArrayList<String> partners = new ArrayList<>(0);

    public ArrayList<String> getPartners() {
        return partners;
    }

    public void setName(ArrayList<String> partners) {
        this.partners = partners;
    }

}`

Comment: This exception is not because of this POJO, check @Yazan's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your APIHelper class to get more information about what you are sending

```
public static APIService apiService;

//this http loggin interceptor allows you debug requests and responses
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
// set your desired log level
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
// add your other interceptors …

// add logging as last interceptor
httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);  // <-- this is the important line!

public static APIService getApiService() {
    if (apiService == null) {
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
    }
    return apiService;
}
```

Maybe you are sending information in a wrong way...
And remember that in server side you must decode the information that receive (with json_decode).